# Deallocate Char Pointer

Tags: c++

I've been trying to deallocate this array of char pointers, but I'm not sure how to fully deallocate it.

Here's the code:

```
char* words[4];
words[0] = new char[8];
words[1] = new char[6];
words[2] = new char[10];
words[3] = new char[16];
```

and heres what i tried

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    delete [] words[i];// this works
}
delete [] words;//this gives an error, not sure why it doesn't work.
```

Can somebody please explain why this isn't correct and how to fix it
thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry this was my first question, so format is off.

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it. All you needed to do was separate your code from your text with blank lines.

Comment: Every `new` gets a `delete`. That's all you need to remember.  You have 4 `new`s and 5 `delete`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only `delete` what you `new`. You didn't `new words`, so don't delete it. Presumably this code is inside a function, in which case `words` has *automatic storage duration* and will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope.

Moreover, don't `new` anything you don't have to, to save yourself the hassle of deleting it correctly (which can be surprisingly difficult). Use `std::vector` when you want a dynamic array, and `std::string` when you want a dynamic string.

Answer (score 4):

It is not correct because `words` is not itself dynamically allocated like the pointers it contains.

`words` is on stack, `words[i]` is on heap. As a general principle you need a `delete[]` for each `new[]`. You have 4 `new` and you need 4 `delete`.

```
char *words[4] // on stack, doesn't need deallocation
char **words = new char*[4]; // on heap, would need deallocation too
```